# Can we install Visual Studio 12 on the Surface RT?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-surface

As I'm planning on getting a Surface RT tablet, I was wondering if it is possible to install Visual Studio 12 on it for app development.

Comment: tablets based on amd-hondo , will be faster, cheaper , and able to run any x-86 software. just wait a little more

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not. Visual Studio 2012 only runs on x86 or x86-64 versions of windows, and Windows RT is based on the ARM architecture.

Comment: Thanks, I need to read more of the difference between those architectures.

Comment: @MimiEAM Think of RT like you'd think of iOS/Android - you can only install software from the App Store due to the different chips. Windows RT is on ARM CPUs. Windows 8 is on Intel/AMD CPUs. To install desktop software, you need an Intel/AMD CPU. Surface Pro will be an Intel chip, so you'll be able to VS2012 on it, when it's released.

Answer (score 6):

You would need to wait for the Surface Pro, which will run Windows 8 Pro on an Intel Core i5 CPU.

Answer (score -1):

Windows RT does not support Visual Studio 2012, because it is  based on ARM architecture. To install Visual Studio you will require a tablet running Windows 8 Pro such as the Surface Pro which will ship in early 2013

Comment: You don't need a tablet to run Visual Studio 2012. You just need a a computer with a x86-64 CPU.  This is just a duplicate of what has already been said.